# Field excitation current increase - affect on the rotor's speed - DC generator - no load

Tags: dc-generator

In a DC generator with no load connected, when we increase the excitation current of the field does the rotor's speed  affected (decreased)? The rotor of the generator is rotated by an external motor. I thought that as there is no current floating on the armature windings, the magnetic field of the armature is not generated and no back-emf is applied. So the speed of the rotor won't be affected by an opposing force as long as there is no load. Does that comply with the reality or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

With no excitation field, the only forces acting on the rotor are friction and the drive motor.

Your argument sounds good, apart from the absence of friction as a participating force.